# Python 3 - how to handle a 53 week years when using timedelta()

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to pull the last 12 full (Monday to Sunday) weeks, but it is failing to do so because Monday 2018-12-31 is week 53 of 2018.

I am deriving the start and end dates of the last full 12 weeks:

```
### determine local time day of and day of week
today = dt.utcnow()
today = today.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz.gettz(timezone_id))

### get the last 12 full Monday to Sunday weeks
timeKey1 = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday()))- datetime.timedelta(weeks=12)
timeKey2 = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday()))- datetime.timedelta(days=1)
timeKey1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(str(timeKey1).rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
timeKey2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(str(timeKey2).rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(timeKey1)
print(timeKey2)
```

Which returns the date range 2018-12-03 to 2019-02-24 which is great:

```
2018-12-03
2019-02-24
```

So when I use this to pull the data I need for that time period I group the weeks together:

```
### Convert timekey to week of year
df['week'] = df['timekey'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: dt.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d").strftime("%W"))

### group the weeks of year together
df['weekCumulative'] = df['week'].ne(df['week'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Then I want my function to continue if the max in df['weekCumulative'].max() == 12:

```
###Check that 12 weeks is available
if df['weekCumulative'].max() == 12:
```

But it fails here because Monday 2018-12-31 turns out to be week 53 of 2018. The below table shows the following:

```
weekCumulative = week of year grouped by weeks 1 to 12
week = week of year
startDate = date of the Monday in each week
endDate = date of the Sunday in each week
```

Table:

```
weekCumulative   week       startDate   endDate
    1             49        2018-12-03  2018-12-09
    2             50        2018-12-10  2018-12-16
    3             51        2018-12-17  2018-12-23
    4             52        2018-12-24  2018-12-30
    5             53        2018-12-31  2018-12-31
    6             00        2019-01-01  2019-01-06
    7             01        2019-01-07  2019-01-13
    8             02        2019-01-14  2019-01-20
    9             03        2019-01-21  2019-01-27
    10            04        2019-01-28  2019-02-03
    11            05        2019-02-04  2019-02-10
    12            06        2019-02-11  2019-02-17
    13            07        2019-02-18  2019-02-24
```

Now what we can see is df['weekCumulative'].max() actually equals 13 because Monday 2018-12-31 turns out to be week 53 of 2018, so it has been grouped into its own group where weekCumulative = 5. When what I actually want to see is this:

```
weekCumulative   week       startDate   endDate
    1             49        2018-12-03  2018-12-09
    2             50        2018-12-10  2018-12-16
    3             51        2018-12-17  2018-12-23
    4             52        2018-12-24  2018-12-30
    5             00        2018-12-31  2019-01-06
    6             01        2019-01-07  2019-01-13
    7             02        2019-01-14  2019-01-20
    8             03        2019-01-21  2019-01-27
    9             04        2019-01-28  2019-02-03
    10            05        2019-02-04  2019-02-10
    11            06        2019-02-11  2019-02-17
    12            07        2019-02-18  2019-02-24
```

Where Monday 2018-12-31 is grouped into week 0 of 2019.

So my questions is, how can this be handled in a way where I don't have to pull the data and then replace week 53 with 00? It would be more efficient to handle it programmatically.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.